# Get data from based on schedule

Tags: mysql

Hi I have following table-
[Location Schedule](http://awesomescreenshot.com/081414hm42)

I want to get campaign_id from this table based on schedule via location_id, if no campaign_id is found according to current schedule then I need default campaign_id (which default > 0). I need your help guys. I will change my table if you suggested me any optimize table.

Sorry for my poor English.

Comment: "based on schedule" - means?

Comment: can you provide proper information?

Comment: I meant current data time, please have look again of my table I add some more data

Comment: please advice my any easiest solution

Comment: means you want campaign_id based on current date and time?

Comment: YES i want campaign id based on current data and time

Comment: Like if I execute it now so I need that campaign id which is maced according to executed data time, Bro am I clear myself to you? or if you have any question please feel free to ask me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66886/discussion-between-mizan3008-and-nody).

Comment: You have to use CASE WHEN statement.

Comment: if you have any sample code for me it will be better for me.

Comment: do you want data based on start_date or on end_date?

Answer (score 0):

Its not Tested. i think its help full for you

```
select * from (
               select *,count(*) as cnt,1 as ord from table1 t 
               inner join schedule s on s.location_id=t.location_id 
               and now() between start_date and end_date
               union all
               select *,count(*) as cnt,1 as ord from table1 t 
               inner join schedule s on s.location_id=t.location_id 
               and default_id > 0
             ) as tt where ord= case when (ord=1 and cnt > 0) then 1 else 2 end
```

Comment: i don't about your tables name. Then only i simply say table1

Answer (score 0):

DB:

```
mysql> select * from schedule_table;
+----+-------------+-------------+
| id | campaign_id | location_id |
+----+-------------+-------------+
|  1 |           5 |          10 |
|  2 |          10 |           5 |
|  3 |           7 |          11 |
|  4 |           6 |          12 |
|  5 |           8 |          13 |
+----+-------------+-------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

x.php

```
<?php

$id = $argv[1];
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:dbname=test;host=127.0.0.1', 'root');
$sth = $dbh->prepare(
    '
    SELECT
        d.campaign_id AS default_id,
        a.campaign_id AS actual_id
    FROM schedule_table AS d
    LEFT JOIN schedule_table As a ON a.location_id = :id
    WHERE
        d.campaign_id > 0
    ORDER BY d.campaign_id
    LIMIT 1
    '
);
$sth->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->execute();
$result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
var_export($result);
```

Result:

```
php x.php 12
    array (
  'default_id' => '5',
  'actual_id' => '6',
)
php x.php 125
    array (
  'default_id' => '5',
  'actual_id' => NULL,
)
```